# C# type-casting sender

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-optimization, unboxing

So I came across this little gem in our codebase the other day, and I wanted to try and see if the person who wrote it was just lazy, or knew something that I don't.

A standard event handler was written like this (I will -

```
private void OnSomeEvent(IVehicle sender, ISomeArgs args){

 if((sender is Car) && (sender as Car).numWheels == 4 && (sender as Car).hasGas) 
 {
     (sender as Car).drive();
 }

}
```

I saw this an immediately thought of the numerous <strike>un-boxing</strike> type-casting operations that are needlessly being done here. I re-wrote it like so-

```
private void OnSomeEvent(IVehicle sender, ISomeArgs args){


 if (sender is Car){
  Car _car = sender as Car;

   if(_car.numWheels == 4 && _car.hasGas){
     _car.drive();
   }
 }     


}
```

So did the first example know something I don't? Does the compiler know that we are trying to  <strike>un-box</strike> type-cast to the same type a bunch of times and do some optimization?

Comment: There's no unboxing going on here at all.  Interface types are reference types.

Comment: Yes I guess your right, I meant type-casting I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already accepted an answer, but I've already done the looking so I figure I'll post it.

Checking the output IL when doing a Release build, there's very little difference between the two setups.

The output IL from the first "unoptimized" call looks like so:

```
// Code size       47 (0x2f)
.maxstack  8
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  isinst     TestApp.Program/Car
IL_0006:  brfalse.s  IL_002e
IL_0008:  ldarg.0
IL_0009:  isinst     TestApp.Program/Car
IL_000e:  callvirt   instance int32 TestApp.Program/Car::get_numWheels()
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.4
IL_0014:  bne.un.s   IL_002e
IL_0016:  ldarg.0
IL_0017:  isinst     TestApp.Program/Car
IL_001c:  callvirt   instance bool TestApp.Program/Car::get_hasGas()
IL_0021:  brfalse.s  IL_002e
IL_0023:  ldarg.0
IL_0024:  isinst     TestApp.Program/Car
IL_0029:  callvirt   instance void TestApp.Program/Car::drive()
IL_002e:  ret
```

The output IL from the second "optimized" call looks like:

```
// Code size       34 (0x22)
.maxstack  2
.locals init ([0] class TestApp.Program/Car c)
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  isinst     TestApp.Program/Car
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ldloc.0
IL_0008:  brfalse.s  IL_0021
IL_000a:  ldloc.0
IL_000b:  callvirt   instance int32 TestApp.Program/Car::get_numWheels()
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.4
IL_0011:  bne.un.s   IL_0021
IL_0013:  ldloc.0
IL_0014:  callvirt   instance bool TestApp.Program/Car::get_hasGas()
IL_0019:  brfalse.s  IL_0021
IL_001b:  ldloc.0
IL_001c:  callvirt   instance void TestApp.Program/Car::drive()
IL_0021:  ret
```

There are additional `isinst` calls being made in the "unoptimized" call, which are good to be optimized away, but won't substantially impact the runtime of the function.

That said, I'd still do the "optimization" as the C# code is easier to read, which is more important than any performance micro-optimizations (until you profile your code and determine that you need to optimize a performance bottleneck).

(Also, the stack is slightly larger, but since it's just a stack increase which is fast and immediately cleaned up, and it's only 6 bytes, it's extremely minor.)

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Very thorough and exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. I can see the extra 'isint' calls in the IL, but like you said there is not that much difference.

Comment: you should also consider the **maxstack**, the optimized code needs only `2` while the other needs `8`. How do you know this `There's no additional casts being done`? I'm not familiar with `IL`.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah, there are additional `isinst` calls being made, which are casts in a way.  I've updated my conclusion to be more accurate and thorough.

Comment: Downvoter - any comment on why my answer is something that should be downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `is` when you use `as` because `as` will return the actual object of desired type if it's castable to that type, otherwise the `null` value is returned. Just checking if it's `null` would be the most optimized way:

```
private void OnSomeEvent(IVehicle sender, ISomeArgs args){    
   Car _car = sender as Car;
   if(_car != null){
    if(_car.numWheels == 4 && _car.hasGas){
     _car.drive();
    }
   }     
}
```

Comment: Even better. Thanks. Any idea on the un-boxing hit in the first example? Was I right to cast once, rather than continually check (obj as Obj)?

Comment: @thebringking `(obj as Obj)` is just a special kind of `Try Cast`, I think the compiler will do it twice, if not the `compilation algorithm` will be more complex. Either way you should go for casting only once, it's also more readable.

Comment: Anyone reading years later.. `if (sender is Car _car) { .. }`

Answer (score 1):

Boxing and unboxing are done only between value types and reference types.

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type object to a value
>   type or from an interface type to a value type that implements the
>   interface.

So there isn't any unboxing in your code. There is only a series of type casting that does not affect performances noticeably.

Comment: Okay, yeah that was brought up. So really it was a micro-optimization for readability. But I guess that is a matter of opinion. Thanks for the feedback!